# A-Frame .obj model displaying but broken

Tags: aframe, .obj, 3d-model

Total beginner to a-frame here, have been through the tutorial scenes and am now setting up my first using .obj models.

Using a remote server, feel like that's important information.

I've seen questions about models not showing up but mine is displaying broken and I'm not sure where to start fixing it.

This is how it looks in windows 3D builder:
[image: Pokemon Stadium Working]

And this is how it looks in my project (backed on pink plane for contrast):
[image]

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pokemon Stadium</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<!-- Scene -->
<a-scene onLoad="">
    <!------------------------------------------------ Assets --------------------------------------------------------->
    <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="stadium-obj" src="assets/models/stadium/Pokemon+Stadium.obj"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="stadium-mtl" src="assets/models/stadium/Pokemon+Stadium.mtl"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="ivy-obj" src="assets/models/ivysaur/Pokemon.obj"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="ivy-mtl" src="assets/models/ivysaur/Pokemon.mtl"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>


    <!------------------------------------------------- Scene --------------------------------------------------------->
    <!-- Skybox -->
    <a-sky color="#279DF4"></a-sky>


    <!-- Abyss -->
    <a-plane scale="1000 1000" position="0 -10 0" color="#212121" rotation="-90 0 0" material="shader: flat"></a-plane>


    <!-- Stadium -->
    <a-entity obj-model="obj: #stadium-obj; mtl: #stadium-mtl" position="0 0 -30" scale="0.05 0.05 0.05" material="side: double"></a-entity>

    <!-- Bulbasaur -->
    <a-entity obj-model="obj: #ivy-obj; mtl: #ivy-mtl" position="15 10 0" scale="1 1 1" rotation="0 90 0"></a-entity>


    <!-- Camera + cursor -->
    <a-entity camera look-controls position="10 12 0" rotation="-23 -90 0">
        <a-cursor id="cursor"
                  animation__click="property: scale; startEvents: click; from: 0.1 0.1 0.1; to: 1 1 1; dur: 150"
                  animation__fusing="property: fusing; startEvents: fusing; from: 1 1 1; to: 0.1 0.1 0.1; dur: 1500"
                  event-set__1="_event: mouseenter; color: springgreen"
                  event-set__2="_event: mouseleave; color: black"
                  fuse="true"
                  raycaster="objects: .link"></a-cursor>
    </a-entity>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to set the type of side of the material to `THREE.DoubleSide`. <s>With A-Frame you should be able to change the type using the following DOM attribute on an AEntity: `material="side: double"`.</s>

If this is not the case, you should update your post with a snippet of your scene elements.

EDIT:

[image: bad image]

As shown in the image, parts of my model are rendered incorrectly. The modelloader in THREEjs reads all meshes in a model and binds them to a grouped object. To fix this, you have to set the side of the material of the meshes to DoubleSided. Luckily in A-Frame, the `obj-model` component emits an event when the model has loaded successfully, we add a listener for the emitted event `model-loaded` on the DOM element and append a callback which returns a customevent. The customevent sends a reference to the model group. Query for the AEntity, I've appended an id `modelEl` to mine.

```
<script>
  (function(modelEl) {
    if (!window['AFRAME'] && !modelEl) {
      return;
    }

    modelEl.addEventListener('model-loaded', function(evt) {
        var model = evt.detail.model;

      traverse(model);
    });
  })(document.getElementById('stadium'));

  function traverse(node) {
    node.children.forEach(function(child) {
      if (child.children) {
        traverse(child);
      }

      updateMaterial(child['material'], THREE.DoubleSide);
    });
  }

  function updateMaterialSide(material, side) {
    if (!material) {
      return;
    }

    if (material instanceof THREE.Material) {
      material.side = side;
      material.needsUpdate = true
    } else if (material instanceof THREE.MultiMaterial) {
      material.materials.forEach(function(childMaterial) {
        updateMaterial(childMaterial, side);
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

After running the above script, my model, and some of the texture loading, has been fixed.
[image]

Something to consider would be digging into creating custom components and modify or extend the obj-model component to prevent having to query for every model that may have the same issue.
If none of this worked, I believe something might be wrong with your wavefront obj export settings.

EDIT2:

Regarding my comment, here is a result of the fixed obj file in A-Frame:
[image]

For convenience sake you can find the MTL and OBJ file here:

[obj file](https://pastebin.com/6RjfeqdE)

[mtl file](https://pastebin.com/T7GpCDai)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shane, that didn't work so I've put up the html

Comment: @JDorman Ah sorry, I've rushed this answer in the train. Possibly you'd have to set the type of side of the material on the **child** meshes. If you are new to THREEjs, this might be confusing at first. The modelloader wraps all meshes into a group element. That group is used to store all meshes from a model. I have updated my example above.

THREEjs is the webgl framework that is being used by A-Frame.

Comment: This looks great, I'll try it tomorrow! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Just tried this and it doesn't seem to work. If it was a problem with the model itself, surely it would also look broken in Windows 3D Builder?

I've set up an example on [Glitch](http://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/e33f4960-348d-4766-a9a3-3dd289c52736)  if that makes things easier.

Comment: Your exported obj file has a broken format for WebGL! During the export of SketchUp to OBJ format, you will have to supply the correct export options. I believe `triangulate all faces` is what you need.

When you import any model into Windows 10's 3D Builder, it should check for errors. It did for me on your SketchUp model and asked to resolve any issues. After accepting the request, it loaded in fine in A-Frame as well. Nothing seems to be wrong with the materials. 

I've updated my post because the children _can_ be a mixture of groups and meshes. You might run into that problem someday.