# 3d model not rendering properly in A-frame

Tags: aframe, 3dsmax, webvr

We are using Aframe for our one of VR app for Samsung Gear. For that, We need some 3d models which we are creating from 3ds max studio. Somehow which ever model we are creating,it is not rendering properly on Aframe. It is not showing material color also some vertexes are not displayed.
I have attached my sample mtl and obj file.
Is this any particular settings which we need to use in 3ds Max studio which we have to use?

[mtl](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4OuOQT6UB3FSTY1b3pSNHJUejQ/view?usp=sharing%22mtl%22)

[obj](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4OuOQT6UB3FMVhyZjFVRkNFZ1U/view?usp=sharing%22obj%22)

Comment: Please don't use files from your Google Drive but use [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [pastabin](https://pastebin.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Without providing an example or a link to the used files to demonstrate what is going on, we can't help you that well. However I recently answered a question that sounds similar. You may want to check that one out: [A-Frame .obj model displaying but broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892281/a-frame-obj-model-displaying-but-broken/43893425#43893425)

If what's mentioned in this answer did not help you, are you able to provide an example of your problem using glitch, plunkr, codepen, etc?

Comment: I have updated my question with obj and mtl file which we have created and not working for us

Comment: Can you add a picture of what it should look like and what it looks like when rendered in WebGL using A-Frame? I don't see any problems on my end other then most of the textures being white, but then again I do not know what the original colors should be. I did notice that the curtains need to be rendered [DoubleSided](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/constants/Materials) if you want to view them from the outside.