# Aframe Model faces not showing

Tags: model, three.js, aframe

I have loaded an obj into aframe but I can't get the face to show correctly. In blender the model looks correct and in windows 3DBuilder the model looks correct. As in this ([A-Frame .obj model displaying but broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892281/a-frame-obj-model-displaying-but-broken/43893425#43893425)) post I have tried to set the Three.js material to doubleside. Not sure if I am implementing the code wrong or if this is actually not the problem. I have uploaded a glitch of my code here (https://glitch.com/edit/#!/beneficial-thumb). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models often need to be simplified to triangles (or quads are sometimes OK) before you can use them in engines like A-Frame, three.js, and others. This model, specifically, has hexagons and more. Opening in Blender shows this:

[image: screenshot of model with non-triangulated geometry]

You can "triangulate" the model in Blender or other 3D Modeling tools, or use online tools (like [this one](https://cesiumjs.org/convertmodel.html)) to convert to glTF, which will automatically triangulate and prepare your model for A-Frame. Afterward you will get a result more like this, which is more engine-friendly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! How would I preserve the materials in the .mtl?

Comment: Triangulating the mesh shouldn't affect your materials at all... do they not appear in Blender, or are they gone after export?